# Temperature array, potentially 2D?

Tags: java

The assignment at hand is below:

Write a program that uses an array to store the temperature for five day objects.
Each object must encapsulate it’s day name (ex: Monday, Tuesday...etc) and temperature
The controlling program will display the average temperature for that week.

Now I understand the basic principle of array's and how they are used, but the I am confused about two things:

```
public class TemperatureAndDay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    double [] temperature = new double [4];

    temperature[0] = 45.24;
    temperature[1] = 67.30;
    temperature[2] = 55.23;
    temperature[3] = 49.20;
    temperature[4] = 50.22;

    }
 }
```

Could anyone give me some tips/hints/examples of code that would give me a better understanding of what my professor wants me to do? Thank you.

Comment: "for five day objects" looks like you need to instantiate objects of a class here, maybe you should write that class?

Comment: P.S. remember that "new array[n]" means that the new array can hold n items, not that n is the maximum index (the max index is actually n-1).

Answer (score 3):

According to the problem statement, I think you should create a `Day` class with data fields `name` (String) and `temp` (double). You could then store five such objects in an array to represent a week, and write a method that loops through this array to determine the average temperature.

```
public static double avgTemp(Day[] week) {
    double avg = 0;
    for (Day d : week) avg += d.temp();
    return avg / week.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a class that holds a day and a temperature (make the attributes public or use getters and setters).
2. Make an array of 5 elements (not 4 like in your example) of that class.
3. Iterate over the array to calculate the average temperature.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a class called Day (or whatever).
2. create attributes: double temperature, String dayName
3. create a constructor: Day(String dayName, double temperature)
4. in some other class, for example, name it TestProgram, create an array of Day objects:

Example:

```
Day[] days = new Day[4];
days[0] = new Day("Monday", 22.44);
...
```

Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @m0skit0 and want to add:

No, it is no 2 dimensional array needed as your headline states. You need an 1 dimensional array that holds the measurements like your sample code does.

Answer (score 0):

> Write a program that uses an array to store the temperature for five day objects.

I'm thinking that you need an array in `main()`, but nowhere else.

> Each object must encapsulate it’s day name (ex: Monday, Tuesday...etc) and temperature.  The controlling program will display the average temperature for that week.

So...what you need to do in a nutshell:

1. Create objects of type `TempDay` or whatever you wish to call it (hopefully meaningful).
2. Have fields in the object for the temperature of that day.  You can populate them any way you wish - through the constructor or mutators.
3. Maintain these objects in an array in `main()` (most likely).
4. The rest is just the raw mathematical definition of "average".

> Could anyone give me some tips/hints/examples of code that would give
>   me a better understanding of what my professor wants me to do? Thank
>   you.

It's my hope that you walk away with more understanding from merely breaking the problem down than just receiving code.  Code can be written by anyone anywhere for any reason; the true mechanical process of *solving the problem posed in the language requested* is what you need to get.

**EDIT:**  The code you have currently also throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to put five elements in an array of size 4.